# What is a "collapsible card docked to bottom of the page" component called?

Tags: component

What is this component called?

[image]

[image]

It's a small modal/card-like container which is docked to the bottom of the screen, usually with the ability to collapse, expand or close. It usually have an header on which you can click to collapse the window.
I have seen it in multiple places so there must be a name for it.

Comment: it's called "collapsible card docked to bottom of the page" (: . I don't feel likely to name everything separately, like after a while of it's common usage it will make them differentiate if it's necessary to re-name this element especially. Idk the exact name for this but I assume they generally categorized as minimized (let's say elements) UI components as I know of.

Answer (score 1):

I think you refering to 2 seperate design patterns here.

- expand/collapse interaction based, which is basically accordion behaviour
- sticky ui elements in the examples is sticky to the bottom of the screen

The components in your examples are a combination of the 2.

Comment: Agreed - no better name for it yet than "sticky collapsible card"